# Template route manager issue

Tags: template-manager

I'm trying to create custom URL's with the route manager.

```
{route='products/overview' series='series' range='range' prod='{url_title}'}
```

in my template named 'overview' I have three products that have been entered and they're linked to via the route path above.  The correct URL does get generated but only one entry is shown for each of the pages, for example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/products/series/range/my_product_1
```

will show 'my_product_1' for each of the products even if the URL is

```
http://www.mysite.com/products/series/range/my_product_2
```

or

```
http://www.mysite.com/products/series/range/my_product_3
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT

I've attached some screenshots of the issue to aid help

[image: route manager]
[image: Template code]

The two screenshots above shoe the route manager and template with the route path

The two below are the web pages that are showing the correct URL's and the correct template  but the same entry for each page.  Just two examples but on the three entries I have set up one entry is shown on all pages.

[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product_range" limit="1"}
{embed="embeds/docHead" my_page_title="{title} | Pico Technology"}
<body>
<!-- Static navbar -->
<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top head-wrap">
{embed="embeds/headNav" myLocation="prod"}
<!-- main body -->
<div class="wrapper body-wrap">
    <div class="container main">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"></a>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col 12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products/oscilloscopes">Oscilloscopes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products/oscilloscopes">PicoScope 2000 Series</a></li>
                    <li class="active">{title}</li> 
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <!-- ABOVE CODE IS GENERIC TO EVERY SUBPAGE -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 leftCol">
                {range_left}
                {left_copy}
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{left_image}" alt="{exp:assets:files}{alt_text}{/exp:assets:files}">
                {/range_left}
                {embed="option_panels/{price_option_panel}"}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 mainContent">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                    <li class="active"><a href="{url_title}">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{url_title}-features">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{url_title}-specifications">Specifications</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{url_title}-software">Software</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{url_title}-documents">Manuals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{url_title}-accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    {overview}
                        <div class="prod-feat-mod">
    {if whatsinthebox != ''}<div class="well pull-right whatsinthebox">
                                {whatsinthebox}
                            </div>{/if}
                            {prod_image}{if lightbox == 'y'}<a class="imgRight zoom fancybox" href="{url}"><img class="img-polaroid img-responsive" src="{url}" alt="{alt_text}" title="{title}"></a>{if:else}<img class="img-polaroid img-responsive imgRight" src="{url}" alt="{alt_text}" title="{title}">{/if}{/prod_image}
                            {prod_copy}
                        </div>
                    {/overview}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- BELOW CODE TO JAVASCRIPT IS GENERIC TO EVERY SUBPAGE -->   
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a> 
<!-- footer -->
<div class="wrapper foot-wrap">
    <footer>

        {embed="embeds/footerPanels"}
        {embed="embeds/footer"}

    </footer>
</div>

<!-- ABOVE FOOTER CODE IS GENERIC TO EVERY SUBPAGE -->

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{path='javascript/{price_option_panel}'}"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="{path='javascript/xdr'}"></script> 
</body>
</html>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how the routing manager works but have you specified a dynamic="off" parameter in your entries tag?

Comment: Can you please include a sample of your template so we could have more information?

Comment: Can you, please, add the [route](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/template_route_manager.html) of the template?

Comment: My route is:/products/{series}/{range}/{prod:alpha_dash}

Comment: dynamic="off" has been set but still not working

Comment: I've just edited my question to hopefully give you more info, cheers

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanGreen. Can you, please, add the code of the `products/osc-overview` template too?

Comment: Thanks @RobsonSobral Products/overview code is added to the question above

Comment: The entries tag quoted in the question does not use `dynamic="off"`, can you double check that you have disabled that for this tag, and update your question accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I can help you.

[The `exp:channel:entries` module just looks dynamically for an entry if its title appears on `segment_2` or `segment_3`](http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/articles/expressionengine_url_schematic). For your template, it appears on `segment_4`. **Buuuuuuuuuuut** template routes overrides this behavior. From the [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html#usage):

> Template Routes overrides the default behavior of URLs, if you wish to use a Channel Entries Tag in your template you must manually provide segments for any parameters that are normally set in the URL. You must provide a segment for pagination, categories, and entry titles if you wish to use those in your Channel Entries Tag. Additionally, be careful when using dynamic=”yes” with Template Routes, this can cause issues if your route does not have an appropriate segment set.

To make it work, set the `url_title` parameter of the `exp:channel:entries` and make it [**not** dynamic](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic).

So, on the template used for a single entry, `products/osc-overview` in your case, replace:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product_range" limit="1"}
```

By:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product_range" limit="1" dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_4}" require_entry="yes"}
```

I added the [`require_entry="yes"`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#require-entry) to allow you to use [`no_results` conditional](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#if-no-results).

The route segment still needs a name. For example, on the current routes setting, the forth segment is being called "alpha_dash", what should be its rule:

```
/products/oscilloscopes/picoscope2000/{alpha_dash}
```

So, add its name and use `alpha_dash` as a [rule](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html#rules):

```
/products/oscilloscopes/picoscope2000/{prod:alpha_dash}
```

Now, the `prod` segment can be accessed on the `exp:channel:entries` module variable by its right name:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="product_range" limit="1" dynamic="no" url_title="{segment:prod}" require_entry="yes"}
```

You can use this logic for your other pages.